# Type Any?! has no subscript member in swift 3

Tags: arrays, dictionary, swift3, xcode8

I have problem with converting a code into swift 3.0 from 2.3.
Here is the my code for swift 2.3

```
var RequestDict = [String: AnyObject]()

func API() {
self.RequestDict = result["rows"]![0]["value"] as! [String: AnyObject]

}
```

This code working fine in swift 2.3 but 3.0 its displaying error.

> **Type Any?! has no subscript member.**

Comment: Why you given negative points for this question? Please explain it.

Comment: You should include the code where you initialise your `result` object. However, even without knowing what type `result` should be, I am pretty sure you are not casting `result["rows"]` to an appropriate type, but keeping it `Any`, which indeed has no subscript member.

Comment: Please [search on the error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+Type+Any+has+no+subscript+members) before posting. This has been answered many times before.

Answer (score 0):

Earlier the code in **swift 2.3** `result["rows"]![0]` was easily compiled without errors. But things have changed in **swift 3** as the resultant is converted to `Any` type and `Any` type has no subscript members.

`result["rows"]` should be first typecasted in `Array` and then from that array you can access the **0th element** which needs to be further typecasted in the type which you are receiving.

If you want the above code to work like before, then you can use `SwiftyJSON` where you can convert your result into a `JSON` object

Assuming your result is an object which has an array named as rows inside.

```
let dictionary = result as! [String:AnyObject]
let yourResultInJSON = JSON(rawValue: dictionary)
```

Then you can easily use this line `yourResultInJSON["rows"]![0]["value"]` which will also be a new `JSON` object where you can fetch your desired key values like:

```
let finalValue = yourResultInJSON["rows"]![0]["value"]
let someValue = finalValue["yourKey"].stringValue   //or intValue or whatever you need to typecast
```